# Scroll only on menu link click

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I have a website I'm working on right now and I'm not quite sure how to get it to behave like I'd like. A rough draft can be found here: www.susmedia.com/NBSigns

I have each "section" put into a div, and when you click on a menu link it scrolls you to the appropriate section. However, when you scroll down, it doesn't really land you on the appropriate sections the way I would like.

What I would really like is a way to not have the site scrollable with a mouse wheel, but still scroll when a link is clicked.  I've tried setting a div around all the sections, setting the height and turning overflow off, but this doesn't really work.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm assuming this will probably need to be done with jQuery, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed. This newb appreciates any direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to disable mousewheel scrolling with jQuery. This should do it:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('mousewheel', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Edit: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/MGZKF/

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks Jake!

One quick question...I'll keep poking around on it, but maybe you can help quicker.  I have a portfolio div with a bunch of photos, and I'd like to allow scrolling within that div, but still not on the page as a whole.  Is there a way to exclude that div while keeping the behavior for the the rest of the page?

Comment: You need to enabled/disable scroll based on the target of the scroll, in that case. I updated the fiddle to show an example of how it could work. There's some extra code in there that prevents the outer box from scrolling if you hit the top/bottom of the inner box: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/MGZKF/1/

Comment: Hey Jake...took me a bit of poking around, but I got it working.  Thanks so much!  You saved me about two months of head scratching!